# What a short way to do foo = bar(foo)

Tags: php, syntax

What a short way to do something like this?

```
$variable = array($variable);
```

To avoid repeating `$variable`

Comment: you mean changing data type or assigning the result of a function?

Comment: How often are you running this small piece of code? It's pretty short as it is, but if you're performing it on 1000 variables, you might want to re-think your process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could make your own function that takes $variable by reference.

```
function makeArray(&$var){
    $var = array($var);
}
$test = "whatever";
makeArray($test);
var_dump($test);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$variable = (array) $variable;
```

Comment: This has the exact same number of characters, and won't give the result you expect if $variable is an array or object.

Comment: Well I don't know where he's up to, if he doesn't explain his question properly I just guess what he tries to say. :)

Comment: @Vince2doom, sorry i forgot to mention that i want to avoid repeating `$variable`